# java Thread doesn't run after 15minutes

Tags: java, multithreading

does anyone know why the thread does not start right away? that is, 10 min, 20 .. Thread do not start ...
logger is simple decorator for java Logger...

here is the code starting:

```
....
log.info("client streams prepared");
messagelistener = new Thread(new Listener(input, this));
messagelistener.start();
log.info("Connection prepared");
....
```

and started listener

```
public class Listener implements Runnable {

    private final MyLogger logger = MyLogger.getLogger();
    private final ObjectInputStream input;
    private final Connection connection;

    public Listener(ObjectInputStream input, Connection callback) {
        connection = callback;
        this.input = input;
        logger.info("Listener created");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.info("listener thread in connection with "+ connection.getUser().getDisplayName() + " is started");
        //.....samecode
        logger.info("listener thread in connection with "
                + connection.getUser().getDisplayName() + " is stopped");
    }
}
```

logs:

```
2013-07-29 22:36:58 MyLogger info INFO: client streams prepared  
2013-07-29 22:36:58 MyLogger info INFO: Listener created  
2013-07-29 22:36:58 MyLogger info INFO: Connection prepared
```

in print see info before start, and after start, but not the first line of the method run, and it's been more than 10 minutes from launch, the system is not loaded, I do not understand why it does not work?
someone is able to explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: replace logger.info  with System.out.println  just to test it out

Comment: Can you show us the whole method, including the declaration, that the listener is created in.  Also, can we see the declaration for `Connection#getUser()`?  Is it possible that you have a deadlock?  Maybe `getUser()` is `synchronized`, and so is the creation method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... and it's been more than 10 minutes from launch, the system is not loaded, I do not understand why it does not work? someone is able to explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

I suspect that the `run()` method is throwing some sort of exception -- possibly a NPE.

```
logger.info("listener thread in connection with "+
      connection.getUser().getDisplayName() + " is started");
```

Any chance that the `connection` is `null` or the `getUser()` returns null here?  I bet that if you just log a simple `"made it here"` method, you will see that in the logs.  You should probably enclose the `run()` lines in a `try {} catch (Exception e) { log exception }` block and log the exception.  I'd also try to use a debugger and put a break point in the first log line and step through it to see what's going on.  See this [debugging tutorial for eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/).

You could also set a `UncaughtExceptionHandler` on your thread to log it that way.  See: [Using UncaughtExceptionHandler effectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535923/using-uncaughtexceptionhandler-effectively)

Another possibility is that your `MyLogger` is logging the `run()` log entries into another file but it looks like the main-thread log messages are using the same logger so less likely.  If this is possible then using `System.out.println("in run()");` at the start of `run()` will help rule that out.

Comment: What files @user1841779?  There is no implicit try/catch inside of a thread `run()` method.  And no implicit logging of exceptions.  You'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: I found a mistake now, as you proposed can getUser may return null, and that has not been able to log into the logger, in the future I will use threads with setted UncaughtExceptionHandler ...