# If a task encounters an exception, its further executions are suppressed. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading

The docs for `scheduleAtFixedRate` and `scheduleWithFixedDelay` say that:

> If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent
>   executions are suppressed

Assuming that my tasks were designed to do some network job and the host was not found. Will the tasks not be executed again ? It may happen that the host is back online the next moment.

Assuming what the docs were talking about was an instance of `RuntimeException`, like array index out of bounds, will tasks will never ever be executed again ? What if I want them to keep executing ?

Comment: Are you asking whether the documentation is lying through its teeth?

Comment: @SLaks -_-" I am asking what if I want the threads to re-execute despite the exception?

Comment: You will have to implement that retry yourself.

Comment: Just catch your possible exceptions and make some treatment or ignore it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis catching the exception as `Exception` will let them execute despite the error, right ? =)

Comment: `Runnable#run()` does not declare a thrown checked exception. The javadoc is referring to an uncaught unchecked exception. As long as the `run()` terminates correctly, the `ScheduledExecutorService` will continue to submit your `Runnable`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That clarifies everything =)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535923/using-uncaughtexceptionhandler-effectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will tasks will never ever be executed again?

That's what "subsequent executions are suppressed" means, isn't it?

> What if I want them to keep executing ?

Don't let `RuntimeExceptions` and `Errors` escape from them.

Comment: An uncaught exception is a sign of an undefined state in the code. That Java then suppresses any further exceptions is an attempt at damage prevention.

Comment: @TwoTheJava doesn't 'suppress further exceptions'. It suppresses further *executions*.

Answer (score 1):

Check about uncatched exceptions inside Runnable action, that you execute by Scheduler. By default JVM don't catch them and thread crashed unnoticed.

---

I suggest to use custom `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, like this:

```
static class MyScheduledThreadPoolExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {
    public MyScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
        super(corePoolSize, threadFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable command, long delay,TimeUnit unit) {
        return super.schedule(new SheduleExceptionCatcher(command), delay, unit);
    }


    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit) {
        return super.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SheduleExceptionCatcher(command), initialDelay, period, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command,long initialDelay, long delay, TimeUnit unit) {
        return super.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new SheduleExceptionCatcher(command), initialDelay, delay, unit);
    }


    /** Wrap for Runnable - for error catching */
    private static class SheduleExceptionCatcher implements Runnable {
        private Runnable task;
        public SheduleExceptionCatcher(Runnable task) {
            this.task = task;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                task.run();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                System.err.println("" + e); // or some logger probably
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

And make some test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2, new PriorityThreadFactory("GeneralSTPool", Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new RuntimeException("Test Error");
        }
    },3000, 3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    while (true){}
}
```

Will print

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Error
```

So your task will execute forever in spite of throwings error.

Comment: You don't need all this. Just catches for RuntimeException and Error.

Comment: Once you forget about try-catch wrapping and will be puzzled about strange code behavior. Multi-threading errors are hard to be found. And also you can't always rely on qualification of your colleagues.

Comment: I can't make head or tail of your first sentence, but the more code you write that your colleagues won't use, the less reason you have to rely on them. You can't solve social problems with extra software engineering, however ingenious.

Answer (score 1):

It was very annoying to not understand where the crash is happening when I forget to catch an exception inside `Runnable`. Actually I didn't need to ignore all these exceptions, I just needed make sure I don't leave them unnoticed. For this purpose I created  [CatchyRunnable](https://github.com/chaschev/chutils/blob/master/src/main/java/chaschev/util/CatchyRunnable.java#L42) class which is a wrapper for `Runnable` which logs exceptions and propagates them if needed:

```
executorService.submit(new CatchyRunnable(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new RuntimeException("log me");
    }
});
```

You could use more concise syntax by applying a Factory Method pattern, I'm just planning to use with lambdas:

```
executorService.submit(new CatchyRunnable(() -> {
     throw new RuntimeException("log me");         
});
```